# Complementary text using replacement

Tags: bash

I have a text file in linux with this kind of format:

```
NODEA_X1
NODEB_X2
NODEC_X1
NODED_X1
```

I want to use the complementary field of one line value X* as below

```
cat file.txt|grep -i NODEA|cut -d '_' -f2
```

if X*=X1 I want the output X2 and vice versa. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{print $1, ($2=="X1")?"X2":"X1"}' file
NODEA_X2
NODEB_X1
NODEC_X2
NODED_X2
```

Comment: This code replaces X2 with X1. But doesn't replace X1 with X2.

Comment: Of course it does, see again all records except #2 in output.